# Commiting into github downgrades my files into previous version

Tags: git, github, commit, repository

Commiting into github downgrades my files into previous version, I have created a second branch in my github repository for experimental uses, and also i have my master branch. Whenever i try to commit to master i get that everything is up to date and my files get downgraded to previous versions. I simply followed these instructions http://learn.github.com/p/branching.html for creating the second branch.
Does anyone had this issue before?

PS:
I am working on a server not locally.
I did not merged the second branch with master.

Comment: Which branch are you on? The master branch or the second branch? Have you committed already (using git add) and have you switched branches (using git checkout master or git checkout secondbranch)?

Comment: I am on the master branch, and yes I have made a commit using, git add.
I used git checkout to make sure that i was committing on master.

Comment: What does this command produce : git status Posting the output here would make it clearer. I would guess you are not committing properly.

Comment: So what has the second branch got to do with it? What is the top entry if you use git log? Do you see your commit there? What does git status say? If you have committed all your changes then it should be clean.

Comment: I mention the second branch because all started after that, before the creation of the second branch I did not had the problem that i am describing.

Comment: The output is "nothing to commit (working directory clean)". 
I use these to commit:
git add . (on master)
git commit -m 
git push origin master

Comment: You say you used `git add`. Did you run `git commit` after that?

Comment: @chepner Yes of course

Comment: Can you see your commit in the log? (git log and then press q to quit)

Comment: No it shows some gits but the last one is not what I commited today

Comment: Sounds like you committed your changes on the other branch. So git checkout your other branch and do git log again. Can you see your commit now?

Comment: It might be easier to find your commit on Github. Is it on the master branch there? Or on your other branch?

Comment: My commit it's in neither branches. It's like I didn't do any commits. A collegue of mine has imported in bitbucket the commits from github, has the problem to do anything with bitbucket?

Comment: I deleted the branch that I had created and commited again, the commit was successfully done and was not downgraded to a previous version. So I hope it works like before now. Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using git reflog to find your missing commit. Here is an explanation from the git ready website:

http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/02/09/reflog-your-safety-net.html

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the branch that I had created and commited again, the commit was successfully done and was not downgraded to a previous version. So I hope it works like before now.